# Probability of getting the only red ball from a box containing $N$ balls

Tags: probability

There's a box with $N$ balls in it. One of them is red and the others white. What's the probability of getting the red ball at the $k$th try ( if you're not putting them back in?) where $k = 1,2,3,\ldots,N$

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect the probability may change?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! We recommend that you provide the work you have done on the problem so that we can help you better. When you have a minute, please take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) 
and look at [how to format mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. Furthermore, I suggest 
that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
for quick reference. Cheers!

Comment: Do you put them back or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will be straightforward,

If the red ball has to come at the $k^{th}$ instance, we must draw white balls till the $(k-1)^{th}$ instance. Probability of getting white balls till $(k-1)^{th}$ instance will be:

$$\frac{N-1}{N} \frac{N-2}{N-1} \cdots \frac{N-k}{N-k+1} = \frac{N-k}{N}$$

Probability of getting red ball at the $k^{th}$ instance will be, $\frac{1}{N-k}$

Probability of getting consecutive white balls will be $1$.

Overall probability,

$$\frac{N-k}{N} \cdot \frac{1}{N-k} \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{N}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the probability to be $1/N$, independently of $k$, directly by noticing that for the first $k-1$ draws you mustn't draw the red ball.

That said, another way to see this is that drawing a single ball from the box in succession until it is empty can be represented by an ordering of the balls (where the $i$-th ball represents the $i$-th draw). In that case, I believe it's pretty clear that the red ball is equally likely to show up in any two positions, and hence the probability does not depend on $k$.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question a bit differently. Suppose $N = 3 $ then there is $1$ red ball and $2$ white. since $k = 1 , 2 , ... , N$ you must make $3$ picks.

On your first pick the probability of drawing the red ball is $\frac{ 1}{3}$ but on your second pick the probability changes because a ball has been eliminated and the probability also depends on what color ball you drew on the first pick. If you drew a white ball on your first pick then there is only one red and one white remaining for your second pick so the probability becomes $\frac{ 1}{2}$. If you drew the red ball on your first pick then the probability becomes $0$ , there are no more red balls.

When you get to your third pick , the probability of drawing the red ball is $1$ or $0$ because there will be only $1$ ball left.